# Swagger - OpenAPI 3.0 : Defining additionalProperties in RequestBody to represent JSON

Tags: json, swagger, gson, swagger-3.0

I have a REST API which accepts application/json in RequestBody. The keys in the json is not predefined. So I have used additionalProperties in swagger to define this JSON. Also, this json may hold JSONArray also.

The problem is, when additionalProperties is used, it is internally taken as Map<String, Object> in the generated java code. This map is deserialized to JSON by using Gson internally. During this conversion, the below json

```
{
  "BooleanField": "true",
  "ArrayField": [
    "SDK ADD",
    "SDK ADD 2"
  ],
  "StringField": "SDK",
  "IntField": "1"
}
```

is converted as

```
{
  "BooleanField": "true",
  "ArrayField": {
    "myArrayList": [
      "SDK ADD",
      "SDK ADD 2"
    ]
  },
  "StringField": "SDK",
  "IntField": "1"
}
```

The json array is put in **myArrayList** key. This causes input validation failure for this request. Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: Can your post your OpenAPI schema definition for this JSON?

Comment: I just used additional properties to represent the entire JSON.

Below is the schema used.

*`AppData:
   title: AppData
   description: Appdata Request Format
   type: object
   properties:
     appData:
       type: object
       additionalProperties: true
`*

Sorry for this bad formatting @Helen